# Electric & Magnetic fields - clarification

Tags: electromagnetism

If (changing electric field)=(magnetic field) and (changing magnet field)=(electric field), then why is there a constant magnetic field around a current carrying wire when the electric field does not change?

Answer (score 2):

Because the full Ampere's law is actually
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B} = \mu_0\left(\underbrace{\mathbf{J}}_\text{current} + \epsilon_0\underbrace{\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}}_\text{changing electric field}\right)\text{,}$$
note that additionally, what it specifes is the *curl* of the magnetic field, rather than the magnetic field itself. But the main problem is that you're ignoring the $\mathbf{J}$ electric current term.

Comment: user2351418: I'd guess you've heard the *changing electric field = magnetic field* explanation used for an electromagnetic wave, where there is no current ($J = 0$). As Stan points out, when $J \ne 0$ the statement needs extending to include the current.

Comment: That's actually **not** the ampere's law, but ampere-maxwell equation!